# Issue with Calling Function

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a method as follows use to correct empty values in Json

```
+(NSString *)CorrectJsonForEmptyValues:(NSString *)pasRawJson
{

    NSLog(@"CorrectJsonForEmptyValues");
    NSMutableString *tmpJson = [pasRawJson mutableCopy];

    [tmpJson replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"[,"
                             withString:@"[{\"v\": \"N/A\",\"f\":\"N/A\"},"
                                options:0
                                  range:NSMakeRange(0, [tmpJson length])];

    [tmpJson replaceOccurrencesOfString:@",,"
                             withString:@",{\"v\": \"N/A\",\"f\":\"N/A\"},"
                                options:0
                                  range:NSMakeRange(0, [tmpJson length])];

    NSString *correctedJson=tmpJson;
    return correctedJson;
}
```

Called the function like this

```
result = [self performSelector:@selector(CorrectJsonforEmptyvalues:) withObject:result];
```

But getting error

```
 2011-11-11 11:11:33.217 HelloWorld10[38833:207] -[Data CorrectJsonforEmptyvalues:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5725cc0
 2011-11-11 11:11:33.219 HelloWorld10[38833:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Data CorrectJsonforEmptyvalues:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5725cc0'
```

If any one can please provide a solution it will be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have declared `CorrectJsonForEmptyValues:` as a class method by starting its declaration/definition with a `+` instead of a `-`.  Therefore you call it on the class object, not on an instance of the class.  If your class is named `Data`, for example, you call it like this:

```
result = [Data CorrectJsonForEmptyValues:result];
```

By the way, you should not start method names with capital letters.

Answer (score 1):

You can call function as follows

```
        [self CorrectJsonForEmptyValues:result];
```

And replace the '+' in the following with '-'

```
    +(NSString *)CorrectJsonForEmptyValues:(NSString *)pasRawJson{
```